# Gumby SCSS Framework - Using Respond for Retina Background Images

Tags: sass, background-image, retina, gumby-framework

Very specific question about working with the respond mixin in the Gumby framework.

To get retina background images working right in CSS, you would need to use the respond mixin (http://gumbyframework.com/docs/mixins/#!/respond), and pass the 'min-device-pixel-ratio' attribute.

I dont think respond in gumby is setup to do this, but maybe somebody on here has tried? It would be easy to do with a traditional media query but I want to use the framework hooks wherever I can, keep my codebase light.

Any insights? Code sample below - I think this is how you would format this in SCSS.

```
  //bg image + container
  .hero-background {
    background: url('../images/image.png') no-repeat bottom center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -2em; 
    min-height: 53em;
    min-width: 100%;

    //for retina background images in Gumby, not sure if this works
    @include respond("min-device-pixel-ratio: 2") {
      background: url('../images/image.png') no-repeat bottom center; 
      background-size: 1429px 538px;
    }
```

This is what I get for CSS output

```
.hero-background {
    background:url(../images/GT_web_trucks_bwphoto.png) no-repeat bottom center;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:-2em;
    min-height:53em;
    min-width:100%
}

@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2){
    .hero-background {
        background:url(../images/GT_web_trucks_bwphoto@2x.png) no-repeat bottom center;
        background-size:1429px 538px
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the generated result?

Comment: I had Gumby running in a Yeoman instance with instant SCSS compiling - so you immediately know if you are screwing it up. Oddly, Gumby will compile but then it just skips over the media query.

Comment: "Skipping" is not possible, not according to the source of the respond mixin:  https://github.com/GumbyFramework/Gumby/blob/master/sass/functions/_responsivity.scss

Comment: Gumby skips over it and still manages to compile the code above if I run the grunt build script. Its just nothing happens. Maybe I should hack that mixin you pointed out. I could build compound media queries in there.

Comment: Are you even looking at the compiled CSS?  There shouldn't be any hacking necessary.

Comment: Like I said, the SCSS complies and just has the regular background reference for both retina and non-retina screens. I'll update the question to show the CSS output.

Comment: @cimmanon - how is this valid question from two years ago being flagged retroactively as off-topic? There was no documentation on this issue, I raised a question and through experimentation proved the hypothesis correct. This isn't 1984 - we don't go backwards and redact out old information just because a framework is no longer in use. Bad form.

Comment: It *should* have been closed as not reproducible back when the question was asked.  You never provided enough information to show how to reproduce your problem, which apparently never even existed according to your self-answer.  You can thank the guy who edited your question recently for drawing attention to it again.

Comment: If this question is off-topic and poorly documented, then Stack Overflow should save the electricity and turn their servers off.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, yes this is possible and the above syntax does work.